# how to run openssl dhparam quietly?

Tags: linux, openssl, tty

I'm writing an install script including generating a Diffie Hellman file with the command

```
openssl dhparam -out /tmp/dhparam.pem 2048
```

As it can take some time and it isn't required for the following steps, I was thinking to make it run in the background but I can't find a way to make it run quietly, it keeps logging in the terminal where the script is running. Here are some failed attempts:

```
openssl dhparam -out /tmp/dhparam.pem 2048 > /dev/null &
openssl dhparam -out /tmp/dhparam.pem -quiet 2048 &
```

It doesn't seem to be writing to stdout, (but rather directly on /dev/tty ?) so I'm out of idea on how to make it quiet: any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you certain the command is not writing output to stderr?  Does the following command run silently as you're expecting?

```
openssl dhparam -out /tmp/dhparam.pem 2048 &>/dev/null
```

Comment: that's it! but what would be the reason to output to stderr? oO

Comment: oh, I think I found why: if no output is specified (-out), it outputs to stdout, which should then not be polluted by all the "." and "+":
`$ openssl dhparam 2048 2> /dev/null`.

That kind of make sense

Comment: @maxlath - *"... what would be the reason to output to stderr"* - Lack of consistency and quality control.

Comment: @jww incorrect. stderr is the proper place for non standard output like debug information.